# Tell loop to only paste in one cell and not all the way down

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a loop that will go thru this data set.

[image]

This is how the output should look.

[image]

Im still getting the hang of loops, but this is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Byte, iLines As Long
j = 1

For i = 1 To 25
   For k = 1 To 8
       If k = 1 Then

           Cells(j, 10).Value = Len(Cells((j + 2), 1).Value) - Len(Replace(Cells((j + 2), 1).Value, ",", "")) + 1
           Cells(i, 11).Value = "SET"

           Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
       End If
   Next k
Next i
End Sub
```

My problem is on my loop output at the moment. It only counts the commas in the first data set and not the other ones. Also where it outputs SET it copies down instead of just putting it in one cell. See Below.

[image]

I will probably have more question as i progress along. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Whenever possible get rid of the loop.  I replaced it with a find to find the next cell with "HW" in it.  It will automatically step from one "HW" to the Next.

When using steps anchor everything on the one row and expand selection using resize.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws

        For i = 1 To 200
            If Left(.Cells(i, 1).Value, 2) = "HW" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                k = .Range(.Cells(i + 1, 1), .Cells(200, 1)).Find("HW").Row
                On Error GoTo 0
                If k <= i Then k = 200
                .Cells(i, 10).Value = Len(Cells((i + 2), 1).Value) - Len(Replace(Cells((i + 2), 1).Value, ",", "")) + 1
                .Cells(i, 11).Value = "SET"
                .Cells(i, 12).Resize(k - i).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(k - i).Value
                i = k - 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott Craner, That works pretty good this seems a little easier to understand than a loop. Can you explain what Resize does? It sounds like you would use it to reference where you would like data outputted.

Comment: I'm also trying to figure out how i would get a blank row after row 3 in column 12?

Comment: @Geoff Resize is very similar to offset, but instead of moving the cell it creates a range of cells.  So Cell(1,1).resize(12) would be the same as Range("A1:A12").  I was thinking about your adding lines,  you will need another counter to count the number of line inserted.  But that is a new question.  I do not have time right now to show you how to do it.  Post it as a new question and someone else may get back sooner, if not I wlll answer when I come back.  But as this answer the immediate question, please mark as correct.

Comment: Sounds Good, @Scott Craner Thanks Again!